# Variables across all view controllers

Tags: swift, variables, uiviewcontroller

In my Login screen, after the login has been accepted, a number is given to that particular user as `UserNum` so i can access information stored in arrays.

My question is: how can i use this variable across all of my viewControllers to display the information that i get from using my array?

Comment: This question is too vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is creating a new Swift Files, and make a struct with static variables  like this:

```
struct CommonValues {
    static var UserNum: Int = 0
}
```

And then, you modify it in any view controller if you need it.

You maybe should save it and load it as well, I recommend UserDefaults for that.

Comment: thank you for this!

Comment: please mark it as answered!

Comment: loads of "this question does not show any research effort" for me

Comment: I'm going to, have to wait 45 seconds apparently