# How can I update the text on another view controllers label?

Tags: swift, view, timer

I am using Swift 3, and I am making an app with multiple views. I have a money system is place and a thing called a business that with a timer makes money on its own. I want the timer to reset the label that displays the money on another view controller.

Is there any simple way of doing this because I have a lot of view controllers with money labels that need to be updated constantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I'll suggest you is to create a "Helper" class and put a variable in that class. Let's say "totalAmount" and whenever your money value is changing, just access the "totalAmount" variable and assign that value to it.
One last thing you have to do is in "viewWillAppear()" method of each "ViewController" set the text of the label by accessing the "totalAmount" variable and getting it's value. In this way you'll always have the updated value, wherever yo go in the app.

Answer (score -1):

You can check my answer here: [Variables across all view controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43792798/variables-across-all-view-controllers/43792895#43792895)
That wold work for your case, sounds a good idea to make a Global Variable.

Comment: Hi, Currently i am using global variables for them variable money, but i want a label that shows the money variable to be changed on a different view controller will that still work?